# Need help resetting the password after getting an ERROR

Tags: c++, string, vector

Hi guys Im just wondering where and how should I make the password reset after inputting an invalid input. for example, after the user inputs the correct password after getting the error, it copies it with the correct password. So when a user puts a "space" in the password and when the error triggers, it keeps giving me the error that my input still has a space even though theres none.`enter code here`

```
do 
{
    int i = 0;
    flag = true;

    cin.clear();                // reset the input stream 
    cout << "Enter your password\n";
    ch = _getch();

    while(ch != 13)
       {//character 13 is enter - carriage return
             pass += ch;
             cout << '*';
             ch = _getch();
       }         

       cout << "\nThe password you entered was " << pass << endl;

       cin.clear();             // reset the input stream 

    while (i < pass.length() && flag)
    {
        if (pass.at(i) == ' ')
        {
            cerr << "ERROR: PASSWORD CANNOT CONTAIN ANY SPACES!" << endl;
            flag = false;
        }
               i++;
    }   

        if (pass.length() < 5)
        {
            cerr << "ERROR: PASSWORD IS TOO SHORT!" << endl;
            flag = false;
        }
          cout << endl; 

}
```

Comment: Your text is almost incomprehensible, but it sounds as if you are forgetting to reset `flag`.

Comment: Sorry, My english is not that good. but yes, how do i reset the flag?

Answer (score 0):

Something this will work:

```
string pass;
bool flag;
do
{
  flag = true;

  cout << "Enter your password\n";
  getline(cin, pass);

  cout << "Pass is " << pass << endl;

  unsigned int i=0;
  while (i < pass.length() && flag)
  {
    if (pass.at(i) == ' ')
    {
      cout << "ERROR: PASSWORD CANNOT CONTAIN ANY SPACES!" << endl;
      flag = false;
    }
    ++i;
  }   
}while(flag == false);
```